# Codeigniter - anchor with confirm first

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to make an anchor in Codeigniter. So, I write:

```
echo anchor("delete?id=".$id, 'Delete', array('onclick' => 'confirm("Are you sure?")'));
```

As you see, when someone click the link, it should show up a confirm pop-up. But it's not working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it gets translated to:

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/delete?id=" onclick="confirm("Are you sure?")">Delete</a>
```

There is problem with double quotes.
The easiest way is to change double to single quotes:

```
echo anchor("delete?id=".$id, 'Delete', array('onclick' => 'confirm(\'Are you sure?\')'));
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. And I just found a mistake, I need to put 'return confirm()' to make it works properly.